# gl_Color is undeclared identifier on WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, fragment-shader

I am looking at http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/glsl/3_glcolor.html which has the following code snippet:

```
void main() {
// Set the output color of our current pixel
gl_FragColor = gl_Color;}
```

I tried to use gl_Color on my WebGL. I got an error that gl_Color is undeclared identifier.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebGL uses Open GL ES 2.0 as its base, therefore you should be using GLSL ES 1.0 for the shaders. GLSL ES does not have a gl_Color, and therefore you will have to rewrite this shader.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just google GLSL ES 1.0. It is on http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf. How do I access the equivalent of gl_Color on GLSL ES 1.0?

Comment: There's no equivalent to gl_Color or any of gl_Vertex, gl_Normal, etc — no aspect of the old fixed pipeline is duplicated or simulated and the functions like glColorPointer don't work in ES 2.0. You need to define your own attribute or uniform as you require, and get/set it in the normal way.

Comment: I am new with WebGL. I am just trying to mix current pixel on the framebuffer with the current texel. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: To use the normal blending mode stuff (glEnable(GL_BLEND), glBlendFunc, etc), just output a pixel with the correct alpha. You can't read back from the current framebuffer, but you can render to texture and then sample from that, though be careful reading from the same texture you are rendering to has undefined results. Amongst other things, being able to read the framebuffer would either introduce race conditions in many implementations of multisampling or else require a much more convoluted and slower hardware path.

Comment: After spending more time on this issue, I end up using multitexture TEXTURE0 and TEXTURE1 to solve my issue. Please see related discussion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476560/multitexture-gl-texture1-issue-on-webgl/4478350#4478350. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -3):

My guess is that you're trying to compile GLSL code using a regular C compiler.

It looks like it's supposed to be C code, but it is actually GLSL source - deisgned to be compiled by the OpenGL GLSL compiler, not your machine C compiler.

The fragment shader has a pre-defined variable 'gl_Color' which is the output from the vertex shader.

The sample you reference has the code inside a shader.frag file, which is referenced by shader.init().  The OpenGL library itself will handle compiling it into GPU instructions for your machine.  Put the code in that file, and hopefully the example will work :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using WebGL on my original post. I am modifying an existing WebGL (and GLSL) example that works already. I just tried to include gl_Color on the above tutorial. It seems that echeese has the correct answer. It maybe WebGL uses the GLSL 1.0.